# How to grab the value in a certain column in a certain row using XLRD

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to loop through a spreadsheet and grab the value of a cell in a row under a certain column, as so:

```
# Row by row, go through the originalWorkSheet and save the values from the selected columns
numberOfRowsInOriginalWorkSheet = originalWorkSheet.nrows - 1
rowCounter = 0
while rowCounter <= numberOfRowsInOriginalWorkSheet:
    row = originalWorkSheet.row(rowCounter)
    #Grab the values in certain columns, say with the 
    # column name "Promotion" and save them to a variable
```

Is this possible? my google-foo has failed me on this one. 
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook


book = open_workbook(path_to_file)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row_values(i)
    variable = row[0]  # Instead zero number of certain column
```

or you can loop row list and print each cell value

```
book = open_workbook(path_to_file)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row_values(i)
    for cnt in range(len(row)):
       print row[cnt]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! Python is new to me, I am in a self education mode at the moment, and this helped clarify some things. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, take a look at the [docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet-class)

Something like this:

```
promotion_col_index = <promotion column index>

list_of_promotion_cells = originalWorkSheet.col(promotion_col_index)

list_of_promotion_values = [cell.value for cell in list_of_promotion_cells]
```

will get you a list of the values in the "Promotion" column